# Sort div data day numeric

Tags: javascript, php

i have a txt file that i read out to display calendar events
the structure form the php file is :

```
<?php
$file = fopen("admin/events/events.txt", "r");
while(!feof($file)){
    $line = fgets($file);
$result=htmlentities($line);
$s = $result;
preg_match_all('/data-day=\'([^\']*)\'/', $s, $matches);
foreach($matches[1] as $idx => $datevalue)
{
    $year = substr($datevalue, 0, 4);
    $month = substr($datevalue, 4, 2);
    $day = substr($datevalue, 6, 2);
}
$line = trim($line);
if ($line != "") {
$line = str_replace("<div data-role='day' data-day='$year$month$day", "<b><u>Datum:</b></u> $day-$month-$year ", $line);
$line = str_replace("'><div data-role='event' data-name='<h6>", " <br><b><u>Event:</b></u> ", $line);
$line = str_replace("' data-start='", " <br><b><u>Start:</b></u> ", $line);
$line = str_replace("' data-end='", " <br><b><u>Einde:</b></u> Tot ", $line);
$line = str_replace("' data-location='", " <br><b><u>Locatie:</b></u> ", $line);
$line = str_replace("</h6>", " <br><b><u>Inhoud event:</b></u><br> ", $line);
$line = str_replace("'></div></div>", "", $line);
echo "<div class='event'>$line</div>"; 
}
}
fclose($file);

?>
```

the txt file that gets read out content is

```
<div data-role='day' data-day='20131202'><div data-role='event' data-name='<h6>event</h6>eventtext' data-start=00.00 ' data-end='9.00' data-location='at home'></div></div>
<div data-role='day' data-day='20140102'><div data-role='event' data-name='<h6>event</h6>eventtext' data-start=00.00 ' data-end='9.00' data-location='at home'></div></div>
<div data-role='day' data-day='20140522'><div data-role='event' data-name='<h6>event</h6>eventtext' data-start=00.00 ' data-end='9.00' data-location='at home'></div></div>
```

Is it possible to sort the events in the php file when they get read out by data-day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a multidimensional array: the first element is the array of dates and second - of lines. Then it is sorted with `array_multisort` So the code is:

```
<?php
$file = fopen("events.txt", "r");
$out_arr=array('sort'=>array(), 'data'=>array());

while(!feof($file)){
    $line = fgets($file);
$result=htmlentities($line);
$s = $result;
preg_match_all('/data-day=\'([^\']*)\'/', $s, $matches);
foreach($matches[1] as $idx => $datevalue)
{
    $year = substr($datevalue, 0, 4);
    $month = substr($datevalue, 4, 2);
    $day = substr($datevalue, 6, 2);
}
$line = trim($line);
if ($line != "") {
$out_arr['sort'][] = mktime(0,0,0,$month, $day,$year);
$line = str_replace("<div data-role='day' data-day='$year$month$day", "<b><u>Datum:</b></u> $day-$month-$year ", $line);
$line = str_replace("'><div data-role='event' data-name='<h6>", " <br><b><u>Event:</b></u> ", $line);
$line = str_replace("' data-start='", " <br><b><u>Start:</b></u> ", $line);
$line = str_replace("' data-end='", " <br><b><u>Einde:</b></u> Tot ", $line);
$line = str_replace("' data-location='", " <br><b><u>Locatie:</b></u> ", $line);
$line = str_replace("</h6>", " <br><b><u>Inhoud event:</b></u><br> ", $line);
$line = str_replace("'></div></div>", "", $line);
$out_arr['data'][] = "<div class='event'>$line</div>"; 
}
}
array_multisort($out_arr['sort'], SORT_ASC, SORT_NUMERIC, $out_arr['data']);
echo join('', $out_arr['data']);
fclose($file);

?>
```

Comment: This code is exactly what i needed. Thx couldnt figure it out myself. Thx alot